# if("hogepiyo".substring(0, "hoge".length()).equals("hoge")がtrueにならない｡

Tags: java

質問はタイトルどおりです｡  なぜでしょうか､実際に文字列を表示して見ても､前者が`hogepiyo`で後者が`hoge`になります｡

Comment: 試してみましたが、[true](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/bbOq7TF9qDlMCkjC) になります。

Comment: 実際のコードにおいては何らかの非表示文字が含まれているのでは？

Comment: 追加の情報があれば回答できるかもしれません。質問者の環境、Javaのバージョン、「"hogepiyo".substring(0, "hoge".length())」の結果のHexダンプはどうなりますか？また細かいことですが質問の前提なので確認させてください。タイトルのif文にはカッコ閉じるが足りませんが、過不足はありませんか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

基本的にそのままで`true`が返りました。

```
if("hogepiyo".substring(0, "hoge".length()).equals("hoge"))
```

実行結果：
http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/7Fb1vz3vZLeAmiXQ

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます｡
よく見るとif文の制御構造を間違えていました｡else文をかかずにifを並べてしまっていたので､このあとのif文で文字列数を超えてif文を評価してしまっていてそこで例外がでていました｡